# Find range of the column where the active cell is

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1000 columns each containing 30 rows of data in excel. I want to write a Macro that will find the average of each column. I want to use `Range("A31:ALL31").Value = "=AVERAGE(current column's range)"`  but i don't know how to get the range of the active column. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Where do you want the average(s) to appear?

Comment: In the row below so row 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure exactly what  you want but this code will put a formula in row 31 from column A to column ALL (that is a column), that averages the rows above starting at row 2.

```vb
    Range("A31:ALL31").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R2C:R[-1]C)"
```

Here's an example of the formula(s) that code will produce.

```
=AVERAGE(A$1:A30)
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work until i changed .FormulR1C1 to .Value so the final code was ```Range("A31:ALL31").Value = "=AVERAGE(A$1:A30)"```

Comment: If I use the brackets on 2, both rows get unlocked. But how to lock the bottom row (removing the brackets doesn't work)?

Comment: Did you change the R1C1 notation to A! notation?#

Comment: I am not sure what the ! means but the code that worked was ```Range("A31:ALL31").Value = "=AVERAGE(A$1:A30)"``` the only thing i changed was putting the $ sign in but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

### Average for Columns of a Range

```vb
Sub AverageTest()
    
    Const rgAddress As String = "A1:ALL30"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(rgAddress)
    Dim arg As Range: Set arg = rg.Resize(1).Offset(rg.Rows.Count)
    arg.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & rg.Columns(1).Address(, 0) & ")"
    
End Sub
```